# MFC measure function in milliseconds

Tags: mfc, ctime

How can i count the millisecond a certain function (called repeatedly) takes ?
I thought of:
`CTime::GetCurrentTM()` before,
`CTime::GetCurrentTM()` after,

And then insert the result to `CTimeSpan diff = after - before`.
Finally store that diff to global member that sum all diffs since i want to know the total time this function spent.

but it will give the answer in seconds and not milliseconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MFC is C++, right?

If so, you can just use `clock()`.

```
#include <ctime>

clock_t time1 = clock();
// do something heavy
clock_t time2 = clock();
clock_t timediff = time2 - time1;

float timediff_sec = ((float)timediff) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

This will usually give you millisecond precision.

Comment: `timediff_sec * 1000` is the millisecond value, otherwise it shows second value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MFC, the nice way is to use WIN API. And since you are worried just to calculate the time difference, the below function might suit you perfectly.

```
GetTickCount64()
```

directly returns the [number of milli seconds that has elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since the system was started.

If you don't plan to keep your system up long (precisely more than 49.7 days), little bit faster version - [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: Because it is based on when system starts, it seems to me this approach has a problem: when a computer very rarely restarts: it may overflow the counter!

Answer (score 0):

The COleDateTime is known to internally work based on milliseconds, because it stores timestamp on its m_dt variable, which is of DATE type, so having resolution for the intended purpose.

I can suggest you to base your time on

```
DATE now= (DATE) COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
```

and after do the respective calculations.